# c++ vector of objects with pointer destructor

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, destructor

I have a problem with destructor. I have two classes: `Map` and `Tile`. They look like this:

```
class Tile
{
  private:
  Tile* parent;
  ...
  public:
  Tile(sf::Vector2f size = { 50.f ,50.f });
  Tile(const Tile& cTile);
  Tile& operator=(const Tile& aTile);
  ~Tile();
  ...
}
```

and

```
class Map
{
private:
vector<Tile*> board;
...
public:   
Map(sf::Vector2i numberOfTiles = { 10, 10 }, sf::Vector2f sizeOfTiles = { 
50.f, 50.f });
Map(const Map& cMap);
Map& operator=(const Map& aMap);
~Map();
...
}
```

Their destructors looks like this:

```
Tile::~Tile()
{
    if (parent != nullptr)
    {
        delete parent;
        parent = nullptr;
    }
}

Map::~Map()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++)
    {
        delete board[i];
        board[i] = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Code is used for shortest path search algorithm. I have to store previous `Tile` so when algorithm find finish it can search backwards shortest path. I can add some more code if it's needed. To sum up: a `Map` object has a vector of `Tiles`, and every `Tile` is initially not pointing to anything. But, if it's used by algorithm than this exact `Tile` stores the position of previous one, and so on to the beginning. I know that smart pointers can probably help me but I thought it would be good for me to learn first how to do this maybe the harder way.

I think that the problem is that (I don't exactly know why) while deleting the `Map` vector with `Tiles` I not only delete the exact `Tile`, but also somehow the `Tile` who is parent of that `Tile`? And, for example, in the next iteration, when it should delete that parent of previous iteration, it cannot because it is already deleted.

I thought that, after the `if` statement inside the `Tile` destructor, it won't be deleted if it already is. But it's not helping.

I've got exception thrown like this:

[image]

And, from debugger mode, I have this:
- first iteration
[image]

- second iteration
  [image]

During analysis from debugger mode, I've start thinking that the destructor of exact `Tile` deletes first parent `Tile`, and than himself. And after that it jumps to the line `parent = nullptr` inside the `Tile` destructor. But somehow only the child `Tile` is being set to `nullptr`.

Comment: What is the ownership relationship? Does each `Tile` have one and only one `Map`? Why does a `Tile` delete its parent when it goes?

Comment: You need to determine whether a `Tile` is responsible for managing the memory of its parent (probably not), or if `Map` is responsible for managing its `Tile`s (probably). Only the class in charge of that resource should be deleting it.

Comment: Reverse the line, `=nullptr then delete` maybe work

Comment: @TheGridLock That would cause a memory leak since the object to be deleted would suppenly be forgotten. `delete nullptr;` has no effect.

Comment: Wouldn't `vector<Tile> board;` be better? Why have pointers to the tiles?

Comment: Omg @Ted Lyngmo . I have encountered this error before, I have done so. It turned out to be a big mistake

Comment: You probably copy objects of type `Map` and/or objects of type `Tile` without having a copy and/or move constructor. Thus the constructors of two objects own and try to delete the same pointers. See also [The rule of 5/3/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: @Tojmak what error are you getting exactly?

Comment: @Ted if `vector<Tile> board` gets resized, the `parent` pointers will be invalidated. This kind of messy parent-child-pointer relationship is... well messy. What's the general idiom to use where object A owns all of object B, but you want to maintain relationships to all of the objects B from some other object C (or possibly from object B like we have here).

Comment: Really this should be vector of smart pointers and the `parent` pointer should also be a smart pointer, fixing that should be the first step here

Comment: @John Resizing the `vector<Tile>` would not invalidate the parent pointers since resizing doesn't move the parent anywhere - but I agree that it can become messy.

Comment: @TheGold I think using `std::shared_ptr` is *a* solution. It just seems like one of these should really be the owner (likely a `Tile` depends on a `Map` to exist, so `Map` should own all the tiles) and the parent-child relationships *should* be references (not in the ampersand meaning, but in the higher level meaning. Maybe `Map` maintains a `std::unordered_map` of `Tile`s and each `Tile` knows the key of its parent)

Comment: @Ted sorry I didn't mean `.resize()` down - I meant if the `vector<Tile>` is increased in size, the objects may be moved if reallocation is required.

Comment: @John It doesn't matter. The `Tile`s can be moved without invalidating the parent pointers.. The parent pointers will still point at the same address. As long as the parent isn't moved, all's well.

Comment: This *has to be* a problem that can be solved with some pre-existing design pattern. I just for the life of me don't know what the design pattern is or what it would be called.

Comment: @Ted I guess I was making the assumption that `Map` owns all the `Tile`s. That's bias on my part about what a `Map` and `Tile` are.

Comment: @John That's my assumption too. As long as `Map` isn't moved, the `Tile`s in it's `vector` can be moved around. They will still point at the same `Map` - but looking closer at the `Tile` it seems that it's parent is another `Tile` - so, my bad I guess.

Comment: I'd be curious what kind of game this is modeling. What game board has tiles that have parents that are other tiles?

Comment: @John that is for shortest path search algorithm. I have to store previous Tile so when algorithm find finish it can search backwards shortest path. I have copy constructor as well as overloaded operator=. I can add some more code if it;s needed. To sum up: Map object has vector of Tiles. And every Tile firstly is not pointing anything. But if it's used by algorithm than this exact Tile store position of previous one, and so on to the beginning. I know propably smart pointers can help me but i though it would be good for me to learn firstly how to do this maybe harder way.

Comment: @Ted  I think that the problem is that (i don;t exactly know why) while deleting Map vector with Tiles i do not only delete exact Tile, but also somehow Tile who is parent of that Tile? And f.e. in the next iteration when it should delete that parent of previous iteration it cannot because it is already delete. I thought that after if statement inside Tile destructor it wont be delated if it already is. But it;s not helping.

Comment: Also i want to mention that in destructor of Tile it helps if i set nullptr to parent before deleting. Don;t know though if it should be done this way.

Comment: @Adrian Mole could you please tell me why it is closed? And reconsider to reopen?

Comment: @Mat could you please tell me why it is closed? And reconsider to reopen?

Comment: @Tanveer Badar could you please tell me why it is closed? And reconsider to reopen?

Comment: @Tojmak Make a new question but include [mcve] so that everyone can copy and compile your code as-is. Also, try to be available after you've asked the question. Not answering peoples questions for 15 hours often often gets questions closed.